# Get content of email sent during command tests

Tags: symfony, email, testing, swiftmailer, liipfunctionaltestbundle

During my tests I call some commands which send emails. I can display the number of emails sent with the following command:

```
$output->writeln(
    $spool->flushQueue(
        $this->getContainer()->get('swiftmailer.transport.real')
    )
);
```

The Symfony2 documentation explains [how to get email content by using the profiler during a Web test](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/testing.html) (also explained here on Stack Overflow), but I don't know how to do the same thing when there is no Web request.

I used the code provided in these links:

```
<?php

namespace ACME\MyBundle\Tests\Command;

use Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class EmailTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function tesEmailCommand()
    {
        // load data fixtures

        // http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/testing.html
        $client = static::createClient();
        // Enable the profiler for the next request (it does nothing if the profiler is not available)
        $client->enableProfiler();

        /** @var \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application $application */
        // inherit from the parent class
        $application = clone $this->application;

        $application->add(new EmailCommand());
        $command = $application->find('acme:emails');
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);

        $commandTester->execute(array(
            'command' => 'acme:emails'
        ));

        $display = $commandTester->getDisplay();

        $this->assertContains('foo', $display);

        // http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/testing.html
        $mailCollector = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');

        // Check that an email was sent
        $this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());

        $collectedMessages = $mailCollector->getMessages();
        $message = $collectedMessages[0];

        // Asserting email data
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Swift_Message', $message);
        $this->assertEquals(
            'You should see me from the profiler!',
            $message->getBody()
        );
    }
}
```

It returns this error:

> Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler::loadProfileFromResponse() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, null given, called in .../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php on line 72 and defined
>    .../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler/Profiler.php:81
>    .../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php:72
>    .../src/ACME/MyBundle/Tests/Command/EmailTest.php:94

The error comes from this line:

```
$mailCollector = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');
```

It seems logical because there is no response since there's no request.

I use Symfony 2.8.7.

---

Here is my Swiftmailer configuration  in `app/config_test.yml`:

```
swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true
    delivery_address: %swiftmailer.delivery_address%
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been able to get it working with:

```
// kernel
$kernel = $this->createKernel();
$kernel->boot();

// container
$container = $kernel->getContainer();

// register swiftmailer logger
$mailer = $container->get('mailer');
$logger = new \Swift_Plugins_MessageLogger();
$mailer->registerPlugin($logger);
```

And then you can get the message contents with:

```
foreach ($logger->getMessages() as $message) {
    $subject       = $message->getSubject();
    $plaintextBody = $message->getBody();
    $htmlBody      = $message->getChildren()[0]->getBody();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. I added the first block before calling the command.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found a solution, instead I made my command more verbose in order to display messages explaining what has been done, which tell me indirectly what is the email content.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the plugin into the mailer:

```
$mailer = static::$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer');
$logger = new \Swift_Plugins_MessageLogger();
$mailer->registerPlugin( $logger );
```

Then you can loop all the messages sent and check the data you need, for instance:

```
foreach ( $logger->getMessages() as $message ) {
    echo sprintf( '%s%s',$message->getSubject(), Chr(10) );
    echo sprintf( '%s%s',$message->getBody(), Chr(10) );
}
```

The key here is having in mind that into the SwiftMail library, the file MailTransport.php dispatches the event "beforeSendPerformed". This event is listened by $logger, instance of Swift_Plugins_MessageLogger. The plugin implements Swift_Events_SendListener interface, one of the methods is getMessages, which contains the content of the messages sent. You can also check swiftmail/swiftmailer number of messages sent in your symfony functional test.

Comment: It produces an error: `PHP Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: …\Tests\Command\CommandTest::$container in /…/Tests/Command/CommandTest.php on line 68`. I use Symfony 2.8.6 and [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle) (it extends `WebTestCase`).

Comment: You will not have any problem if you extend from KernelTestCase. In case you extend from WebTestCase you can use profiler for checking it: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/testing.html (please ensure profiler is enabled in your test/dev environment yml files).

Comment: Thanks but this link was already in my question. I don't know how to access to the profiler, I don't have any *client* when I test the command.

Comment: Notice that if you extend from WebTestCase, you can instantiate the client by typing  $client = static::createClient();

Comment: It seems illogical to create a client when no request will be made. I'll have to try this anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of extending from WebTestCase you must extend from KernelTestCase. Once done this you can gain access to container by:

//start the symfony kernel
        $kernel = static::createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();

        //get the DI container
        self::$container = $kernel->getContainer();

Comment: I had no error when I used `$mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('swiftmailer.mailer'); …`, but `$logger->getMessages()` is empty. I'll update my question with more details.

Answer (score -1):

You can 'fake' a request like so, this *might* help you out.

```
$this->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
$request = Request::create('http://yourdomain.com'));
$this->getContainer()->set('request', $request, 'request');
$this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext()->setHost('http://yourdomain.com');
```

I have a function which does similar in commands where I use services where a request needs to be present.

Comment: Where should I put this code? What is the link with `$client`?

Comment: I don't understand how to get the content of the email with this code.

Answer (score -1):

You can add custom channel for Monolog and send email content to log file.

In config.yml add

```
monolog:
    channels: ["mm"]
    handlers:
        mm:
            level:    debug
            type:     stream
            path:     "%kernel.logs_dir%/mm.log"
            channels: ["mm"]
```

and then in command code use:

```
$logger = $this->get('monolog.logger.mm');
$logger->info($emailContent);
```

Comment: I don't have the email content, I'm looking for a way to get it, like Swiftmailer can return the content of sent emails.

Answer (score -1):

By default SwiftmailerBundle add message logger plugin

```
$this->getContainer()
    ->get('swiftmailer.mailer.default.plugin.messagelogger')
    ->getMessages();
```

You can use it in commands tests.

Comment: I tested it and it returned an empty array.